# Spring Security 3.0.5

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm rolling back from Spring Security 3.1.0.m1 to 3.0.5 but I'm using the security="none" and that's not in the 3.0.5 schema.  Anyone know how I accomplish the same thing in 3.0.5?

```
    <http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/preregistered/*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute filters="none". Please also see [Intercept-URL element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e7341)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to consolidate the multiple `<http>` elements into a single `<http>` element with multiple `<intercept-url>` elements. Additionally, as Ritesh says, you will need to use the `filters="none"` attribute on each of these `<intercept-url>` elements, e.g.

```
<http ... >
    <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
    <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
    <intercept-url filters="none" pattern="/preregistered/*" />
    <intercept-url pattern="... your other patterns..." access="..."/>
    ...
</http>
```

Hope this helps!