# Perhaps bad configuration of FacesServlet

Tags: jsf-2, security, web.xml, jaas

With this following web.xml the tag jsf are rendered but i have many trouble with templates,  css and buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>

        <!-- Applicazione Web -->
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Applicazione</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
                    <http-method>GET</http-method>
                    <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>


        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>         

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Instead this is my login.xtml that is located in / folder of my application

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" template = "/WEB-INF/template/login.xhtml" >

    <ui:define name="areaLogin">
     <p>Login to access secure :</p>
     <h:form >

        <h:panelGrid styleClass="myTable3" columns='2' border="1" >

            <h:outputLabel value='Username: ' />
            <h:inputText value="#{beanLogin.username}" />

            <h:outputLabel value='Password: ' />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{beanLogin.password}" />

            <h:outputText value='' />

            <h:panelGrid columns='1'>
       <a4j:commandButton action="#{beanLogin.login()}" value="Login" onclick="selezionaClientiAttivi();selezionaFattureInScadenza();selezionaOrdiniNonFatturati();" status="StatoLogin"  />
       </h:panelGrid>
      </h:panelGrid>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

as said above the jsf components are rendered but the tempate is not called and the a4j:commandButton not work , instead if i remove the security contraint and change welcome-file-list

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

everything work fine

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Your faces servlet is fine. Your security constraint is just wrong.

Comment: how can fix it ? i want that all urls are protected (/*)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13823189/1530938