# PrimeFaces based application with PicketLink does not show style in login page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, picketlink

I developed a PrimeFaces based application that I now want to protect with PicketLink in a CDI way. I followed [this example](http://www.ocpsoft.org/security/simple-java-ee-jsf-login-page-with-jboss-picketlink-security) and created a login page with several PrimeFaces components including a layout). All styling and functionality is however lost. Even a simplified login.xhtml page (to match the example linked to above) does not have styling.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head/>
<h:body>
  <p:panel>
    <h:form method="POST" prependId="false">
      <p:inputText id="j_username" />
      <p:password id="j_password"/>
      <p:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{identity.login()}" ajax="false"/>
    </h:form>
  </p:panel>
  <p>Tip: you can login with a username/password of jane/abcd1234.</p>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason the css and js files are not loaded is because the security 'profile' in the original example has **all** resources protected besides a login.xhtml file. JSF by default loads resources from the 'virtual' `javax.faces.resource` folder. This needs to be excluded from authentication to. The HttpSecurityConfiguration in the original example should be adapted to exlude this virtual folder in the config.

```
public class HttpSecurityConfiguration {

    public void onInit(@Observes SecurityConfigurationEvent event) {
        SecurityConfigurationBuilder builder = event.getBuilder();

        builder
            .http()
                .forPath("/javax.faces.resource/*")
                    .unprotected()
                .forPath("/index.jsf")
                    .unprotected()
                .allPaths()
                    .authenticateWith()
                    .form()
                        .authenticationUri("/login.jsf")
                        .loginPage("/login.jsf")
                        .errorPage("/error.jsf")
                        .restoreOriginalRequest()
                .forPath("/logout")
                    .logout()
                    .redirectTo("/index.jsf");
    }
}
```