# Link to primefaces theme stylesheet is missing session id

Tags: primefaces, picketlink

I've added a primefaces theme to the web.xml...

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>le-frog</param-value>
</context-param>
```

... and get a link to the stylesheet in the head ...

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/pos2hue/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-le-frog" />
```

...which would be correct, if we wouldn't use single-sign-on, which redirects all URLs without a sessionid to the login screen. So the stylesheet resolves to:

```html
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>HTTP Post Binding (Request)</TITLE></HEAD><BODY Onload="document.forms[0].submit()"><FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="https://configured.identity.url"><INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SAMLRequest" VALUE="..."/></FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Other links coming from primefaces are OK, for example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/contextroot/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.jsf;jsessionid=eo0Oo0oK37AUm7bNOaFqdrB-?ln=javax.faces"></script>
```

As additional info I have to add:

- session mode in web.xml is set to "URL" (i don't want to change that)

```xml
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

- for single-sign-on we use picketlink (i have a picketlink.xml in the WEB-INF folder)
- web server is JBoss EAP 6.1

Any ideas, how i could

- make primefaces add the sessionid to the stylesheet href?
- make an exclusion to the single-sign-on mechanism?
- or make it work otherwise?

Adding the stylesheet directly is possible, but unwanted, because we use a JSF2 template for all applications, but i want to configure it for one application only.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your 'good' example is not PrimeFaces but plain jsf. A session id should either be in the url or in a cookie. Test on both. And maybe the user just does not have a session yet. And how to exclude the resourses? Let me find a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces based application with PicketLink does not show style in login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373178/primefaces-based-application-with-picketlink-does-not-show-style-in-login-page)