# Uncaught reference error: Primefaces is not defined in Login Page with Spring Security+ Jsf2.2 primefaces 4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security, themes, jsf-2.2

I have a project using login from database with Hibernate Annotations and jsf 2.2 with `primefaces` 4.0. the login works fine, but the components in the view "login.xhtml" doesn't look like primefaces components, look like only `jsf` components.

**Spring-security.xml**

```
     <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
     <http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/AccesoDenegado.xhtml" use-expressions="true" >

    <!-- Se definen los dos perfiles y se interceptan las paginas para realizar la autenticacion-->


        <intercept-url pattern="/page1**" access="hasRole ('ROLE_PROFE')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/page2**" access="hasRole ('ROLE_ALUMNO')"  />
        <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>


         <!--Se define una pagina de login personalizada, no a que viene por defecto-->

         <form-login 
         login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
         login-page="/login.xhtml" 
         authentication-failure-url="/login"
         />

          <!-- Cerrar Sesion-->

          <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout- success-url="/" logout-url="/logout" /> 


    </http>

   <!--Autenticación de uuarios de la BBDD-->
    <authentication-manager >
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

`MyUserDetailsService`

public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

```
 UserDao userDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String usuario)throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    proyecto.login.user.modelo.User user = userDao.buscarUser(usuario);

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);


}


private User buildUserForAuthentication(proyecto.login.user.modelo.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsuario(), 
        user.getContraseña(), user.getHabilitado(), 
                    true, true, true, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<Roles> userRoles) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (Roles userRole : userRoles) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRol()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}

public UserDao getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}

public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}
```

}

`LoginBean`

```
public class LoginBean {

   /*este metodo se llama cuendo el usuario pulsa "acceder"*/
    public String doLogin() throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                 .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        // It's OK to return null here because Faces is just going to exit.
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Login.xhtml**

```
<p:messages globalOnly="true"/>



<!--Para q pueda soportar el Spring Security Check no hay q cambiar ID-->
<p:panel header="Autenticación" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

<p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Usuario " />  
<p:inputText id="j_username" required="true" label="username" />  
<p:message for="j_username" display="text" style="color:red"/>

<p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Contraseña" />  
<h:inputSecret id="j_password" label="password" required="true" />  
<p:message for="j_password" display="text" style="color:red"/>

<p:outputLabel for="_spring_security_remember_me" value="Recordarme" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox    id="_spring_security_remember_me" />        



    ![</h:panelGrid>      
    <p:commandButton type="submit" id="login" value="Acceder"  action="#{loginBean.doLogin}" />


    </p:panel>

   </h:form>
     <!-- Boton de Home -->

     <br/>

 <h:form>   
         <p:commandButton action="home?faces-redirect=true" value="Home" /> 

</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>]
```

These components are not PrimeFaces. Here's the screen shot:

[image]

**Error in the browser's builtin JS console , Google Chrome**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces CSS skin not showing in login page, also JavaScript undefined errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822978/primefaces-css-skin-not-showing-in-login-page-also-javascript-undefined-errors)

Answer (score -1):

I solve my problem using this: 
[What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

i added properly the css page in Login Page

Comment: @BalusC The problem was that the css library wasnt included in the login page (on <h:head>), so i  found in the link i posted, the right way to include the css library on Login Page

Comment: ok so i could change the question to Uncaught reference error: Primefaces is not defined in **Custom** Login Page with Spring Security+ Jsf2.2 primefaces 4, because you said that in Spring Security Login Page theres no need to include the css library , right?

Comment: My login page is not the original Spring Security form, is customized , i translate it to spanish. So when i include the css library on <h:head> it works fine. You told me that if it was a standard Spring Security login page, it wont need to declare the css library on the <h:head>. So i would change my question to: "Uncaught reference error: Primefaces is not defined in** Custom **Login Page with Spring Security+ Jsf2.2 primefaces 4 "  for those people who have custom login pages in spring security and primefaces and have the same problem.